# The meaning of 'I'm blowing it' by Superman

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I'm translating 'Superman' from English to Hungarian, and I don't get the meaning of the following sentence:

> "I'm blowing it"

The context is that he realizes that the 'S' sign is a symbol in a different world, and he makes it out that it must be his legacy.

Can someone explain it, please?
Thanks!

Comment: https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/blow+it

Comment: More detailed context please!  Is this from a comic, a film, a tv series?  Which one? A link to the source would be ideal.

Comment: To make out means to decipher something.

Comment: @whiskeychief The OP did not say "make it out as if something", which is not idiomatic anyway. The proper expression would be: to make something out as being x or as x.

Comment: @Lambie The OP said “makes it out that”. This does not mean decipher something.

Comment: @whiskeychief The expression in English posted by the OP is not idiomatic. "Make it out that" is not English. **To make something out to be** is. And he could have meant decipher. "He makes it out to be his legacy.". He interprets the symbol or deciphers the symbol as his legacy. Now it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

This is not entirely a question of English - but here goes - 
Although most of the US public assumes that the logo on Superman's chest is an "S" that stands for *Superman* (which it probably did when the character was originally created)  we are told now in various comic books, movies, tv shows etc that the symbol is really a sigil of the El family which, in its Kryptonian etymology stands for "Hope".

So Superman is saying that he is supposed to represent or bring hope but, at that moment, he was not doing a good job of that.

Comment: Put another way, “I’m blowing it“ means I’m failing.